# how can I update a field using previous register in Alteryx?

Tags: alteryx

I Have three fields, stock, date and sales. The stock in first date have a value (Initial stock), but I need that the value of stock in next row be the value of stock in the last row minus the value of sales of current row. Is possible update a field using previous register in Alteryx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: use their [Multi-Row Formula](https://help.alteryx.com/10.0/MultiRowFormula.htm) tool, it allows exactly what you describe: your expression would look something like `[stock] = [row-1:stock] - [sales]`

Comment: This is the solution!